# What is the technical difference between seperated javascript files and merged files in same order

Tags: javascript, merge

Im trying to merge javascript files, however after merging some errors occur. The order of the files are the same just merged into one file, and no compression used.

What is the technical difference between seperated javascript files and merged files in the same order?

Greetings,

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: You may have an ASI or `use strict` issue.

Comment: Hi, it starts with some Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. Causing more inline scripts to also fail.

Comment: What functions aren't defined? What & where are their definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description and error message are consistent with the use of IIFE/IEFE, where you don't terminate them with a semicolon.

An example:

```
(function(){
   console.log("one"); 
})()

(function(){
   console.log("two"); 
})()
```

If the above two snippets are in separate JavaScript files, they will happily execute without error. However, put them together and you will see:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

The reason is the lack of semicolon after the first, causing the second to be joined on. It's trying to call the return value of the first, like a function, and that return value is `undefined`.

Comment: Sounds good! Thx i will investegate this and return with an awnser.

Comment: I also had to add a jQuery $j=jQuery.noConflict(); But the very last thing i did to make it work was adding a semicolon to superfish.js, so i guess this awnser should be marked as the awnser ;) Thx for the help MrCode!